# How to restructure Linq query to avoid using Contains() inside an Any() lambda expression (need a ContainsAll())

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, lambda, contains

I have a query, which throws an exception in Linq to Sql.

`Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator.`

I have seen plenty of related questions so I (roughly) understand the reason WHY it doesn't work (the value `term` in the lambda expression cannot be converted into a string value for the SQL query), but I cannot see HOW to should restructure this.

```
var searchTerms = userQuery.Split(' ').ToList().ConvertAll(term => term.ToLower());

var qry = (from tree in someQueryable
           join widget in myDb.Widgets
           on tree.ParentId equals widget.Id
           where
               searchTerms.All(term => tree.Title.ToLower().Contains(term)    //Can't use Contains on term, as term isn't a local variable
               || searchTerms.All(term => widget.Title.ToLower().Contains(term)    //And again here
               || (tree.Description != null && searchTerms.All(term =>
                                                tree.Description.ToLower().Contains(term)))    //And here
           orderby tree.SomeDate descending
           select tree);
```

**How can I get all `trees` whose Title, Description or ParentWidget.Title contain ALL of the search terms?**

I have tried iterating over each term, however this gives me the issue of matching a single term, not all terms.

*Update*
I resolved the issue... by changing my requirements :) 
I am still very interested to know how my initial requirements could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

```
from term in SearchTerms
from tree in someQueryable
join widget in myDb.Widgets
where tree.Title.ToLower().Contains(term) ||
      widget.Title.TowLower().Contains(term) ||
      (tree.Description != null && tree.Description.ToLower.Contains(term))
orderby tree.SomeDate descending
select tree
```

Comment: Hi msarchet, I just tried out your solution, and it seems to be matching results for a single term. For example, if my search terms are "foo" and "bar", it will return items with "foo" but not "bar", and visa versa.
Could you please elaborate a bit on how the first part of your query works?
When you say "from x in foo from y in bar" is that the same as "for each x in foo, (do each y in bar query)"?